# External documentation in Intellij

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, documentation

Currently, I'm working on the project using the Spring framework.
I'm wondering if I can add spring documentation so when I click ctrl + q I get relevant information.

I tried to add a link to the external documentation path in SDKs but it does not work.
I changed the maven option to always download documentation but it doesn't work.
I wonder if there is a way to add this documentation.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you open up a method you don't have the sources for (`CTRL + mouseclick or "B"`), IntelliJ will display a menu "`download sources`" in the upper right corner of the class file. That usually works for me (without adding external documentation paths).